# AngularJS matching filters exactly and not part

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

```
<li class="column__list--item" ng-repeat="skill in skills | filter: { skillset_id: filterbySkillset }">
```

I've noticed that when I try filter using the above, it filters anything it partly-matches. So if I have `skillset_id`'s of `10` `11` `12` and `filterbySkillset` is `1` then it would match `10` `11` `12`

But what I need is it to match *exactly* and not *partly*

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ngRepeat` supports strict filter comparison. You just need to set `:true` as [comparator](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) in filter definition:

```
ng-repeat="skill in skills | filter:{skillset_id: filterbySkillset}:true"
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I've spent some time trying to look it up and all I could find was people saying to use custom filters!

Comment: Well you may need custom filter for specific situations, but for this one, above solution should be enough.

Comment: I have another issue with filtering, will put up another question though as you have answered this one.

Comment: Feel free to comment you next question here, maybe I would be able to help on the next on too.

Comment: Here is an example of custom filter you can use http://plnkr.co/edit/Hp6vJu2L5ikDWbmWXSTC?p=preview. Not sure about the purpose of all other stuff in your fiddle.

Comment: I ended up putting each of them into an array and then using `:true` I was able to get it working